# How to install Netbackup software in solaris?

Tags: software-installation, solaris, backup

How do I install NetBackUp software in solaris?

I'm learning the software and I need to install and practice using it.

Comment: what version of Solaris do you have ? what version of NetBackUp do you want to install? some more details please.

Answer (score 1):

After skimming through the [Solaris basics](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/servers-storage-admin/o11-083-ips-basics-523756.html) I understand it's something like:

```
# pkg update
# pkg search netbackup
```

and then install with

```
# pkg install <result_pkg>
```

Comment: Only if netbackup is provided in one of the package repositories you have configured, which given it's a commercial package sold by Symantec, it may not be.

Answer (score 0):

Generally the install process is:

> ./install

However depending on exactly what you want, there may be more to it. As an example, have a look at [this post](http://www.symantec.com/connect/forums/netbackup-client-install-solaris) on the Symantec forums - the OP needed to get the path right.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a fair amount of information -- version of Solaris and Netbackup, as well as if this is on the client or server side.

I know if the server side is Solaris, and the client as well, that you could install the Solaris client from the Java GUI.

Although, configuring Netbackup is where it'll get complicated.